# Transpose Large Data with multiple fields

Tags: excel-formula, transpose

I have a large Excel file where data is collected 48 times per day for the month, but this has been collected vertically rather than horizontally.

I need to split this for each date of the month but the data is going back 3 years meaning I would have to do a transpose formula over 340 times.

Is there a quicker way of doing this?

Current Format:

[image]

Desired Format:

[image]

Comment: A pivot table should do this.

Comment: Yes, pivot worked, it's always the simpilest of answers haha.